# Unique notation to search for compounds in PubChem and in Chembl

Tags: notation, databases

I am not a chemist, I come from a computer science background. I am working on a project related to computer-aided drug design.

I have a list of chemical compounds in their SMILES notation, to which I am trying to retrieve some chemical properties. Some of these chemical properties exist in the Pubchem database, others exist in the Chembl database.

As an example:

- Isoniazid (INH)'s SMILES in PubChem is : C1=CN=CC=C1C(=O)NN
  https://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/3767#section=Canonical-SMILES
- Isoniazid (INH)'s SMILES in Chembl is : NNC(=O)c1ccncc1
  https://www.ebi.ac.uk/chembl/compound_report_card/CHEMBL64/

Which means that if I were to use these SMILES as a key for my (automated) search, I will get chemical properties for different compounds.

Now, my question is: Is there some unique key, that exists in both databases (PubChem and Chembl) that I can use for my search?

Also, if possible, can anyone explain why these SMILES are different even for the same compound. As I was reading in a website, that these are canonical SMILES which I beleive are specific to each database.

Comment: InChi keys are unique (with very limited exceptions). 
You could also pre-process your SMILES through some kind of standardisation code to get them all into the same format

Comment: @NotEvans. Depending on what you aim for, *standard* InChI/InChIKey (version 1.06, December 2020) may be good and efficient.  They may lead to confusion, too.  Because Amine Chadi stated a background different to the one of a «chemist by training», I sense *potential* (though not insurmountable) pitfalls using them and appended my answer.  Version 1.06+ possibly growths and improves by feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is *not one*, but *there are multiple* approaches to describe a molecule by a SMILES string. It is up to the developers of the programs (and databases) to define which one is used and to declare this in the documentation.  Thus, read the manual; if they do not state this explicitly, ask them.

One of the better approaches taken is, for example the one by [OpenBabel](https://open-babel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/FileFormats/SMILES_format.html); it offers you to write e.g., *either* a canonical, universal, or inchified SMILES string.

If SMILES you work with have origin in multiple sources adhering to more than one dialect, you may request e.g., OpenBabel to consolidate the representation you subsequently use.  Thus

```bash
obabel -:"C1=CN=CC=C1C(=O)NN" -ocan
```

yields to the canonical SMILES string `NNC(=O)c1ccncc1`.  In case you have a file listing many SMILES, consider a conversion like

```bash
obabel -ismi input.txt -ocan -O output_canonical.smi
```

Noel M O'Boyle wrote a paper about the methods to identify a canonical SMILES representation of (organic) structures which provides insight here, too.

*Towards a Universal SMILES representation - A standard method to generate canonical SMILES based on the InChI* in *J. Cheminf.* **2012**; [doi 10.1186/1758-2946-4-22](https://jcheminf.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1758-2946-4-22).

---

A comment suggested to use [InChI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Chemical_Identifier) and their hashed form, InChI keys as a replacement of SMILES.  Their spread in databases ([example NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?Name=alanine&Units=SI), or examples compiled by Warr) may be tempting and checking *identity* of entries based on InChI key appealing in terms of performance and collision resistance once they are in hand (e.g., Goodman *et al.*).

*However*, the discern of different compounds which are [tautomers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautomer) of each other currently *is not* possible using *standard* InChI/InChI key.  Take, for example, 2-hydroxypyridine and its tautomer, 2-pyridone.  Depending on the polarity of the solvent, one form may be favoured over the other; and while both structures differ, and are described by two different canonical SMILES, the *standard* InChI and InChIKey are the same for both:

[image]

because

> «different tautomers have the same connectivity/hydrogen layer»
>
> see 4.7. Standard InChI specifics, InChI trust's [Technical FAQ](https://www.inchi-trust.org/technical-faq-2/) by 2012-05-12

What can be done, e.g. using InChI trust's reference binaries (version 1.06/December 2020, [repository](https://www.inchi-trust.org/downloads/)), is to invoke the inclusion of a *fixed H layer* then leading to InChI

```
InChI=1/C5H5NO/c7-5-3-1-2-4-6-5/h1-4H,(H,6,7)/f/h7H
InChI=1/C5H5NO/c7-5-3-1-2-4-6-5/h1-4H,(H,6,7)/f/h6H
```

and

```
InChIKey=UBQKCCHYAOITMY-QDQILVOLNA-N
InChIKey=UBQKCCHYAOITMY-BRMMOCHJNA-N
```

As of now, the inclusion of a *fixed H layer* in InChI leads to a non-standard description (thus, there is no leading `1S`).  Equally note that only the second hash block is affected to yield a different InChIKey.

Thus, ***in short*** depending on what you aim for, use InChI/InChIKey with caution.

References:

Goodman, J. M.; Platnev, I.; Thiessen, P.; Bolton, E.; Heller, S. R. *InChI version 1.06: now more than 99.99% reliable* in *J. Cheminform.* **13**, 2021, 40; [doi 10.1186/s13321-021-00517-z](https://doi.org/10.1186/s13321-021-00517-z), open access.

Warr, W. A. *Many InChIs and quite some feat* in *J. Comput. Aided Mol. Des.* **29**, 2015, 681–694; [doi 10.1007/s10822-015-9854-3](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10822-015-9854-3).

Comment: Thank you for the great informative answer.